# SharePoint Online Search Returning Items from Recyle Bin

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I have Search Results web part which is displaying deleted items that are now located in the Recycle Bin.  Has anyone see this or know why?  I don't want such items to be visible in my search result.

Thanks

Comment: This is too odd. I would file a trouble ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the incremental crawl must have not taken place so you can see the items in search. Try to do full crawl to verify the searhc results.

Comment: we have done that - still not removed. :(

Comment: there are 2 recycle bin ... have you removed items from both of them ?

Comment: yes.  all items are removed from all recycle bins.  We now if a ticket open with Microsoft

Comment: the search result that you get, did u try to click on link / url if any.  it might take you to the url of that item . somewhere that item might still exist.